# Druapl LDAP Module Error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am trying to install DRUPAL LDAP module. But I am getting the following error:
No LDAP PHP Extension is loaded for PHP, so LDAP will not work properly.

I am new to drupal. Please help. I have drupal  installed on my local. If any php extension is to be added, please let me know the location

How to fix ths issue?
[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFwzS.png)

Comment: Did you check with readme.md and install.md file inside the module.
Check this link https://www.drupal.org/node/2895364

Comment: both files are present under ldap. check what there?

Comment: checked that link. I am unable to understand that

Comment: Check whether you have installed this extension http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php in you PHP

Comment: what is pear library?

Comment: Are you using Linux if yes follow the link https://www.mysysadmintips.com/linux/servers/187-installing-ldap-support-in-php-on-ubuntu-lamp-server

Comment: Run phpinfo() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to see do you have LDAP enambled or not. Check the link  from @PraveenKumar's post to see how it should look like.

Comment: Find here instructions for some other OS-es: https://mametrockafella.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/installing-ldap-support-in-php-on-ubuntu-server/